# Larger YouTube thumbnails

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, video-thumbnails

I've been using the Youtube API to grab thumbnail images of selected videos but I need them to be a little bigger.

I need 4(ish) thumbnails at a decent size, at the moment I can generate these 3 images.

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cj6ho1-G6tw/1.jpg

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cj6ho1-G6tw/2.jpg

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cj6ho1-G6tw/3.jpg

But they are TINY.

I was just wondering if anyone had found a way to generate slightly larger thumbnails like the cover one.

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cj6ho1-G6tw/maxresdefault.jpg

This might just be something that you simply cannot do with the API but it's certainly worth a punt. I'm also open to non-API suggestions no matter how hacky.

*Please note: I need all 4 thumbnails to come from the SAME video at set intervals, much like the 3 referenced above*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hq before number: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cj6ho1-G6tw/hq3.jpg

As I've seen - you can't use maxres thumbnails with numbers (only maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: Very nice, Cheers! It's a shame it only works on HQ videos though but I'm sure I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the thumbnail will not exist with that link.
If so, you could try: https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/[video id]/mqdefault.webp
Or https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/[video id]/hqdefault.webp

mqdefault stands for Medium Quality
hqdefault is self explanatory